# Subscription packages and storing them

Tags: php, mysql

I'll be offering a few web-based services soon, and I'm working on the subscription system. Users pay monthly (or can pay for some months in advance), but I offer different packages. The different packages allow them to use the system for x minutes per day.

So for example

Package one lets them use it for 2 minutes a day
Package two lets them use it for 5 minutes a day
Package three lets them use it for 10 minutes a day

and so forth. These are all monthly.

My current method will let me set their package and when their subscription ends. I want to change this so that they can have multiple packages.

My problem is this:

They buy package one. They use it for two days and decide they want to upgrade to another package. They buy package two. Now they have 2 months (minus the two days), but it would be for package two. Essentially they just got an extra month of package two for the price of package one.

So my idea is this:

I can store each transaction separately, and in each transaction set when that package ends and which package it is. Then I can `` SELECT `package` FROM `packages` WHERE `status`='active????' ORDER BY `package` DESC LIMIT 1; `` This would allow me to select their higher package and give them that until that one becomes inactive, and then revert to the lesser package. The problem is that this `` `status`='active' `` doesn't keep track of the dates. How can I go about doing this properly?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with "pay per minute" deals and it is a horror story. At least the scenario I was presented with was since client side timing and server side can be two different worlds (like streaming video that pauses to load vs. the actual time the user has been on the page determined by a date diff).

Here's how we handled it though - aside the balancing for hiccup compensation - 
The user buys minutes plain and simple. If they upgrade they are returned the prorate for unused minutes according to the price set when they purchased them AFTER being charged for the new minutes. That way you don't lose out if there is a problem charging them after the refund takes place.
The refund was not a literal transaction. It dumps into a balance associated with the user and then reduces the upgrade price by the prorated refund. Returning the paid minutes to zero - before adding the new upgrade minutes.

The holes in the system were solved by reducing each "unit" to its lowest form and basing the economy off that number. So there is no "package" to speak of. There is only number of minutes associated to the user and cost per minute according to when they purchased them. That way if your rates change it does not affect old users who may have prepaid years in advance.

Mind you, this is a reduced example. The actual system was enormously complex.

For your scenario, the daily limit is just a relational table that stores date and collective page time on an individual load basis, however you choose to determine that. Not a single entry that tries to accumulate, but individual entries as small as you can collect and sum them any chance you can. This will save you a lot of time when someone complains that their computer froze and they lost their minutes beyond their control.
So when your sum script detects the minutes have met or exceeded according to their current limits it just refuses access.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one package. While upgrading you should subtract  the number of minutes  used in new old package. Just keep the old package is history for records.